# Query ES with different search term and result consisting content of 1st search term on top priority

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an existing index `abc_index` that contains `title` `description` fields. Now i have added `skill_ids` to index. Below are the few documents in index

skill_ids is mapped as `keyword`

| Doc id | title | decription | skill_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| before_skill_doc_1 | artificial intelligence | dec of AI | [] |
| before_skill_doc_2 | the power of AI | power of artificial intelligence | [] |
| after_skill_doc_1 | title with skill 001 | description of skill 001 | ["12345"] |
| after_skill_doc_2 | title with skill 002 | description of skill 002 | ["12345"] |

Now i want documents with skill_id having "12345" (i.e doc after_skill_doc_1 and after_skill_doc_2) should come up on top and then documents which have "artificial intelligence" in title & description below.

below is the query

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "skill_ids": {
                        "value": "12345",
                        "boost": 2.0
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "query": "artificial intelligence",
                      "fields": [
                        "title^35",
                        "description^15"
                      ],
                      "type": "phrase"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Actual Outcome** - Documents where "artificial intelligence" is in title or decription are ranked first.

**Expected Outcome** - Documents where skill_ids are matched should be given top priority and then title or description should appear.

Answer (score 0):

I did this query where I put the boost 100 in skill_ids.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "skill_ids": {
              "value": "12345",
              "boost": 100
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "artificial intelligence",
            "fields": [
              "title^35",
              "description^15"
            ],
            "type": "phrase"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Still, the result having "artificial intelligence" in the title, description is ranked above.

Comment: you tried decrease boost in title e description?

Comment: tried. results were different this time. Got 1st content which has skill_id but 2nd content didn't have skill_id

Comment: I tested with four docs in your questions. Your test has more documents?

Comment: yes. it has millions of documents. this was just give overview and be precise